# Splitting OGG and M4A audio files without transcoding

Tags: audio-editing

I am looking for some (free or paid) softwares, APIs or programming libraries (any programming language) for splitting OGG and M4A audio files without transcoding.

By splitting I mean: transforming a 10 minutes audio file of 10 min and split it into two files, one with 4 min and other with 6 min.

Comment: Have you tried ffmpeg?  See this [Superuser answer](https://superuser.com/a/525217/314998)

Comment: Hell yea! Just used ffmpeg and made it work. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to split the audio using ffmpeg for Windows https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

1. Unzipped the program to a desired location.
2. Opened cmd in Windows.
3. Navigated to to the ffmpeg-(version-code-here)/bin/ folder
4. Ran the command

   ffmpeg.exe -ss 30 -i "D:\Songs\my-audio.m4a" -c copy -t 60 "D:\Songs\my-audio-splitted.m4a"

This command is splitting the audio file after -i parameter from second 30 to second 90 (30 + 60) and saving it at "D:\Songs\my-audio-splitted.m4a"

- **-ss 30** means the split will begin at the 30th second of the audio file
- **-t 60** means the split will end counting 60 seconds from the informed start, so the split will end at the 90th second

If -ss is not informed, the split will assume the start is at 0 second

If -t is not informed, the split will assume the end is the end of the audio

I am not sure what ffmpeg is doing (if its transcoding or not), but it is a really fast processing, so I am assuming it is doing what I want.

Credits for [@StarGeek at the comment section](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/55545/splitting-ogg-and-m4a-audio-files-without-transcoding?noredirect=1#comment77260_55545).

Comment: Using the copy option, it shouldn't be doing any transcoding, just a straight stream copy.  I believe that if it were a video file, it would have to be cut on a key frame, but I'm not sure about the case with a .m4a file.

Comment: That's a good question. Is there such thing as a key frame in audio files? Probably yes.